# How to set a setTimeOut to avoid script unresponsive inside .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

How can I add a setTimeOut to avoid script unresponsiveness inside a each loop?, basically there is this grid where I have many rows, and the rows have a column that consists of a kendo datepicker. The problem is that after a few a bound to the grid i get the unresponsive script box, then i have to click continue and it would work:

```
var j = 0;

$$('.dtInputs'),each(function (input){

    j++;
    input.kendoDatePicker();
    if(j > 500){
       if(j % 1000 = 0)
       {
           window.setTimeOut(arguments.callee, 1);
           return false;
       }
    }
});
```

The problem is that by looking at this i dont think it will continue adding the datepicker after it returns false to the remaining inputs. Not sure how to do this.

Comment: `window.setTimeOut` is _undefined_. Perhaps you meant `window.setTimeout`? (note casing)

Comment: if you're using a kendo grid, you should consider using its editing and virtual scrolling abilities - creating that many widgets at once usually doesn't lead to a good user experience (and the user typically only interacts with a few of the widgets anyway, I assume)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `.each` itself is synchronous.

- You can off-load your script to [webworkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers)
- Or make an async loop yourself using `setInterval`

In your case, this should work

```
$.fn.asyncEach = function(callback){
  var i = 0;
  var elements = this;
  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    callback.call(elements[i],elements[i]);
    if(++i >= elements.length) clearInterval(timer);
  },0);
}

$('.dtInputs').asyncEach(function(){
  $(this).kendoDatePicker();
});
```

Note that I'm using timers to force asynchronous behavior. It will prevent blocking the UI, but will be significantly slower in processing.

Comment: sorry i am kind of new to Jquery, how would i be able to apply the above given my scenario?, i would really appreciate it.